# How to split a form background color in c# so one half is black and the other is white

Tags: c#, forms

I am stuck on figuring out how to split the background colors so the left side of the form is black and the right side of the form is white in response to the ClientSize of width and height and when the form is clicked, the background color inverses

Comment: Do you have any code to illustrate how and where you are stuck so someone can help?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two panels both equal to 50% of the form.  You can then manipulate their background color.